# How to extract axios response data into variables in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to achieve the same functionality as the `...mapState()` function in Vue.

I have an axios request that returns an object with different props, like this:

```
axios.get(
 '/'
).then(
 res => {
  console.log(res) // {name: 'foo', age: 22, height: '1.72m', job: 'developer'}
 }
)
```

Now, in the same way as `...mapState()` can I extract the props so I can use them in my template like:

```
<template>
 <div> 
  Hello My name is {{name}} and I am {{age}} years old
 </div>
</template>
```

I was thinking about assigning the response object to the vuejs data, but I have other variables that I don't want to be re-written

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
axios.get(
 '/'
).then(
 res => {
  console.log(res) // {name: 'foo', age: 22, height: '1.72m', job: 'developer'}
  return { index: res}
 }
)
```

then you can access the data

```
<template>
 <div> 
  Hello My name is {{index.name}} and I am {{index.age}} years old
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This seems better than the other (deleted) answers I got. Are you sure it works though? There is nothing binding `{{index}}` to the global vars

Comment: i don't know what your mean? use {{index.name}} to get the value

Comment: what is the exact result of the console.log(res)?

Comment: the response is okay, just the interpolation isn't working